# method POST not supported issue in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting method POST not supported error while passing value arg in @RequestMapping like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cancelLoanApp.rm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
cancelLoanApplicationSubmit(@ModelAttribute("cancelApplication") 
                        CancelApplicationEntry cancelApplication{
...
...
}
```

But when I am doing like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{pathURL}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cancelLoanApplicationSubmit(@ModelAttribute("cancelApplication") 
                        CancelApplicationEntry cancelApplication, @PathVariable String pathURL){
    pathURL = "cancelLoanApp.rm";
    ...
    ...}
```

my code is working fine and hitting the mapped method but @ModelAttribute is appending double entry in string fields. Please can some one explain the difference both are making.

Comment: what is `cancelLoanApp.rm` rm specifies  .rm is mapped to your URL mapping?

Comment: and how you are calling your second method in above code?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA yes . <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.rm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: @KalaiselvanA I am calling the methods using spring:form and method="post"

Answer (score 0):

when ever your using like `value = "/cancelLoanApp.rm"` ,it will act as a request url path not as a parameter.
but if you try like this `value = "/{pathURL}"` pathURL act as a placeholder for value.

note : request path does not accept `.`

Comment: I am using same pattern at one more place. there it is working fine. Please suggest..